# Shell / Ruby / RubyMine: Accessing underlying shell environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell, rubymine

I am trying to run a shell *my_command* from rspec, and bump on a issue related to shell environment variables (I'm running RubyMine on Ubuntu)

- The *my_command* needs specific environment variables which are defined in ~/.bashrc file.
- When running this *my_command* purely from the console it works perfectly
- This *my_command* is also used in one of my rspec example
- When running my test suite from the command line it works perfectly

I'm facing an issue when running my test suite through Rubymine. RubyMine is setting its own environment variable for some reasons, and obviously it does not include the environment variables specifically needed by the *my_command*.

I do know how to set the environment variables in RubyMine's Run/Debug Configuration window, but I don't want to do this because 1) there are several environment variables concerned 2) I would have to change the configuration every time to reflect the system update.

So I wonder how to access the underlying (i.e "original") shell environment variables programatically, in order to restore them during the execution of the *my_command*?

Note I tried to source ~/.bashrc before running *my_command* with `source /home/me/.bashrc && my_command` but it (strangely) cannot find the file, with the message: "sh: 1: source: not found"

And clue are welcome. Thanks

Comment: have you tried `source`ing the file before running your shell command? EG `\`source ~/.bashrc; my_command\``?

Comment: Hi. Yes I did, I forgot to mention in my question. Kindly see my edit

Comment: Does RubyMine run from a different user?

Comment: `ps aux` confirms its launch by my user. A details, it's running through java executable, does it have an influence on this?

Answer (score 1):

Variables set in ~/.bashrc are not available by default to programs started from the graphical environment in a desktop session. You can set the variables in ~/.profile

For more information, you can take a look at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)